# L'expression « (il ne) manquait plus que ça »

Tags: sens, expressions

> **Manquait plus que ça...** Ils ont amené d’autres amis, cette fois !

Le contexte :

La dernière fois que les deux parties se sont réunies pour une négociation, ils n’étaient que trois à faire face à l'interlocutrice. Comme si ce n'était pas déjà assez pénible, cette fois-ci ils viennent juste de se pointer avec cinq personnes de plus dans leur sillage.

---

Évidemment, l’emploi de l'ellipse laisse penser qu’elle se plaint de quelque chose, mais comment utilise-t-on cette expression, au juste?

Comment: [Exprime l'exaspération face à une mauvaise nouvelle qui vient s’ajouter à d'autres soucis préexistants](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/il_ne_manquait_plus_que_%C3%A7a). In English we'd say "that's all we needed!"

Comment: Expressions similaires: "Et pour couronner le tout" (négatif ou positif), "la cerise sur le gâteau" (négatif ou positif), "la goutte d'eau qui fait éborder le vase" (négatif), et bien d'autres (car en France, on aime bien se plaindre...).

Comment: Just saying there is a typo in @MorganFR's comment, it's ***d**éborder le vase*.

Comment: @SimonDéchamps Oui, c'est bien entendu "déborder", c'est en effet une typo, désolé. Clavier de gamer oblige, les touches "zqsd" ne fonctionnent pas toujours.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

L'idée c'est qu'on a déjà une bonne dose de mauvaises nouvelles, ou de situations désagréables, et qu'une dernière vient se rajouter. "*ne manquait plus que ça*" pour avoir toutes les pires choses possible (en gros). On ne peut pas faire pire.

Comme si c'était la dernière mauvaise chose qui peut arriver, tout le reste est (malheureusement) déjà arrivé.

Il est possible que ça soit à la base ironique, l'utilisation "*normale*" étant quand tout est réuni pour que ça fonctionne, le dernier élément arrive et "*ah, il ne manquait plus que ça, maintenant (que c'est là) c'est parfait*". C'est la même idée, mais avec des choses négatives. (D'ailleurs c'est quasiment jamais utilisé positivement)

C'est un peu la même idée que "*c'est la totale*", on a réussi à avoir toutes les pires choses possibles en même temps.